# Java ServerSocket accept function giving Timeout exception every time

Tags: java, networking, serversocket

I am learning networking in Java. I tried a code that uses the `ServerSocket` class. But the serversocket is not able to establish a connection every time. I tried various port numbers, longer timeouts, but nothing works. Here is my code for the Server:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;

class TestServer extends Thread 
{
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    public TestServer(int port) throws IOException
    {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        serverSocket.setSoTimeout(60000);
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try 
            {
                System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " + serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

                System.out.println("Just connected to " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                System.out.println(in.readUTF());

                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                out.writeUTF("Thanks for connecting to " + socket.getLocalSocketAddress() + "\nGoodbye!" );
                socket.close();

            }
            catch(SocketTimeoutException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Socket timed out");
                break;
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `TestServer` class performs both client and server side operations on the `run` function being called. I don't get where am I going wrong. My class containing main function is:

```
import java.io.IOException;

class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        TestServer server = new TestServer(port);
        server.start();
    }
}
```

I am new to Java networking, so please be considerate about some silly mistake and let me know what have I done wrong.

Comment: Where is your client code? What are you using to connect to the server?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Both are in the same `try` block inside `run` function.

Comment: There is no client code in the `run()` you have shown. There is only server code, a `Socket` returned from `ServerSocket.accept()` is not itself a client, it is just the server's side of a connection initiated by an outside client. You need a separate `Socket` that `connect()`'s to the `ServerSocket`'s port for its `accept()` to act on. Do you have such a client that connects to the server?  It sound like maybe you do not, which would explain why your `accept()` times out. There is nothing for it to return because nothing is trying to connect to it yet.

Comment: As a test, create a `TestClient` thread class that creates its own `Socket` and `connect()`s it to the `ServerSocket`'s port. Have your `main()` start a `TestClient` thread after starting the `TestServer` thread. Oh, and your `main()` needs a loop or something to prevent it from exiting while your thread(s) are running, otherwise your app will terminate prematurely.

Comment: @RemyLebeau that worked. can you add it as answer so I can select it?